# Eye Diagram of QPSK Modulated Signal

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter, modulation, finite-impulse-response, qpsk

I need to plot eye diagram for RRC filtered QPSK modulated signal. The specifications are given as follows

Sampling frequency : $1.024$ MHz

Symbol Rate : $256$ Kbps (Hence, Upsampling rate = $4$)

Roll off factor = $0.2$

So I wrote a matlab code, but the resolution of eye diagram plotted is very low. I used object commscope.eyediagram.

Increasing the sampling frequency gives a better resolution, but it also increases the number of taps in the RRC filter which would not be a viable option for hardware implementation.

Kindly suggest what changes I need to make to get a better resolution of eye diagram without increasing the sampling frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kindly suggest what changes I need to make to get a better resolution of eye diagram without increasing the sampling frequency?

There is none, since the resolution of your eye diagram is directly linked to the sampling rate of your *observer*. In your case, that observation rate is identical to the sampling rate of your signal-producing system.

However, in reality, you'd use an oscilloscope that has a sampling rate much higher than your transmitter.

You can simulate the same – just use a proper *interpolator* between your modulator's output and your eye diagram's input. Pay attention to the fact that an insufficiently designed interpolation filter will distort your signal – and that is exactly the reality of digital transmitters: the reconstruction filters after the DAC distort the signal, too, and so does the RF channel between a transmitter and the oscilloscope (and of course, the filters and active components inside an oscilloscope do that, too).